# How to include a column in a group by without unwanted values

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Okay, this might sound lame but what I am going to ask may look a bit kiddish. But still I would always prefer to spill my heart out here than anywhere else.

So I have a table called **TEMP_CALC** which is as follows :

```
  COUNTRY   CITY         TEMP
=============================
   US      Arizona       51.7
   US      California    56.7
   US      Bullhead City 51.1
   India   Jaisalmer     42.4
   Libya   Aziziya       57.8
   Iran    Lut Desert    70.7
   India   Banda         42.4
```

So, the table consists of sample data for some temperature ratings in regions (just some test data).

What I want is a query that would display the cities with maximum temperatures along with their country name and the temperature rating itself.

The query I made would either give me the Country name and maximum temperature or gives me all the rows in the table.
What I tried so far is as follows:

This gives me only **COUNTRY** and **TEMP** -

```
****************************
select country,max(temp) 
from temp_calc
group by country
```

And when I try to include the city name attached to these temperatures then it gives me all the rows in the table -

```
*************************
select country,city,max(temp) 
from temp_calc
group by country,city
```

I want the city with the maximum temperature along with the country name and the temperature rating itself.

Comment: Maybe add len(country) to see if they are truly the same.

Comment: @Anthony Horne it throws an error, **invalid identifier "LEN"**

Comment: Sorry = Native MSSQL here - use LENGTH( string1 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the city with the highest temperature for each country. This is typically done using window functions:

```
select country,city,temp
from (
  select country,city,temp, 
         row_number() over (partition by country order by temp desc) as rn
  from temp_calc
) t 
where rn = 1
order by country, city;
```

Comment: Or use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` in order to consider ties.

Answer (score 1):

You have the solution in your first try:

```
select country,max(temp) 
from temp_calc
group by country
```

You just need to add the corresponding city to the result set. You could do this:

```
 with max_temp as (select country, max(temp) m_temp 
    from temp_calc
    group by country)
 select country, city, temp 
 from temp_calc where 
 temp=max_temp.m_temp and 
 country=max_temp.country;
```

This should allow you to filter the results from the table based on the maximum temps.

Comment: You are missing the join to max_temp and an `IN` clause instead would feel more natural anyway.

Comment: I started with an in clause, but I wanted to make sure that if the same temperature appears in more than one country we can filter by both, and with seemed like an easy solution.

Comment: Obviously you have never used `IN` clauses on more than one column. It's simply `where (country, temp) in (select country, max(temp) ...)`

Comment: Thanks! I will use it in the future.

Comment: @Assafs The solution is legit though it seems a bit complex. Nevermind, thanks for considering the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
select *,  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by country order by country,temp desc) as sortid, 
 from temp_calc  ) t 
 where sortid =1
```